# Flyway Baseline command throws error if flyway_schema_history already has migrations

Tags: database, postgresql, migration, flyway

I've been trying to create a new baseline for the flyway setup. I already have the complete setup and ran a few migrations already. Now, I want to setup a new baseline. On running the flyway baseline command, i get an error "Unable to baseline schema history table 'public'.'flyway_schema_history' as it already contains migrations".

The only possible solution i found is to remove this table, run the baseline command and then run migrate command. It is working as expected. But is it a recommended solution?